# Stack overflow when trying to implement lock-free queue

Tags: c++, multithreading, queue, lock-free

I implemented a lock-free queue based on the algorithm specified in Maged M. Michael and Michael L. Scott work [Simple, Fast, and Practical Non-Blocking and Blocking
Concurrent Queue Algorithms](https://www.research.ibm.com/people/m/michael/podc-1996.pdf) (for the algorithm, jump to page 4)

I used atomic operation on `shared_ptr` such as `std::atomic_load_explicit` etc.

when using the queue in one thread only, everything is fine, but when using it from different thread, I get a stack overflow exception.

I could not trace the source of the problem unfortunately. it seems that when one `shared_ptr` is getting out of scope, it decrements the number of references on the next `ConcurrentQueueNode` and it causes an infinite recursion, but I can't see why..

the Code:

the Queue node:

```
template<class T>
struct ConcurrentQueueNode {
    T m_Data;
    std::shared_ptr<ConcurrentQueueNode> m_Next;

    template<class ... Args>
    ConcurrentQueueNode(Args&& ... args) :
        m_Data(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}

    std::shared_ptr<ConcurrentQueueNode>& getNext() {
        return m_Next;
    }

    T getValue() {
        return std::move(m_Data);
    }

};
```

The concurrent queue (note: not for the faint hearted):

```
template<class T>
class ConcurrentQueue {
    std::shared_ptr<ConcurrentQueueNode<T>> m_Head, m_Tail;

public:

ConcurrentQueue(){
    m_Head = m_Tail = std::make_shared<ConcurrentQueueNode<T>>();
}

template<class ... Args>
void push(Args&& ... args) {
    auto node = std::make_shared<ConcurrentQueueNode<T>>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    std::shared_ptr<ConcurrentQueueNode<T>> tail;

    for (;;) {
        tail = std::atomic_load_explicit(&m_Tail, std::memory_order_acquire);
        std::shared_ptr<ConcurrentQueueNode<T>> next = 
            std::atomic_load_explicit(&tail->getNext(),std::memory_order_acquire);

        if (tail == std::atomic_load_explicit(&m_Tail, std::memory_order_acquire)) {
            if (next.get() == nullptr) {
                auto currentNext = std::atomic_load_explicit(&m_Tail, std::memory_order_acquire)->getNext();
                auto res = std::atomic_compare_exchange_weak(&tail->getNext(), &next, node);
                if (res) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            else {
                std::atomic_compare_exchange_weak(&m_Tail, &tail, next);
            }
        }
    }

    std::atomic_compare_exchange_strong(&m_Tail, &tail, node);
}

bool tryPop(T& dest) {
    std::shared_ptr<ConcurrentQueueNode<T>> head;
    for (;;) {
        head = std::atomic_load_explicit(&m_Head, std::memory_order_acquire);
        auto tail = std::atomic_load_explicit(&m_Tail,std::memory_order_acquire);
        auto next = std::atomic_load_explicit(&head->getNext(), std::memory_order_acquire);

        if (head == std::atomic_load_explicit(&m_Head, std::memory_order_acquire)) {
            if (head.get() == tail.get()) {
                if (next.get() == nullptr) {
                    return false;
                }
                std::atomic_compare_exchange_weak(&m_Tail, &tail, next);
            }
            else {
                dest = next->getValue();
                auto res = std::atomic_compare_exchange_weak(&m_Head, &head, next);
                if (res) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
};
```

example usage that reproduces the problem :

```
int main(){
    ConcurrentQueue<int> queue;
    std::thread threads[4];

for (auto& thread : threads) {
    thread = std::thread([&queue] {

        for (auto i = 0; i < 100'000; i++) {
            queue.push(i);
            int y;
            queue.tryPop(y);
        }
    });
}

for (auto& thread : threads) {
    thread.join();
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I guess I count myself fortunate that my concurrency needs are always met by garden-variety mutexes, with well-defined semantics, and that I don't need to fool myself into sinking massive amounts of time on shaky, convoluted, "lock-free" alternatives, that, strangely enough, always end up implementing looping spinlocks that effectively block execution, just like an ordinary mutex would.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I guess you are right, but it always good experimenting

Comment: If you're going to implement something that is lock free, I suggest your standard implementation returns `true` for a call to `std::atomic_is_lock_free( &ptr )` where `ptr` is some `std::shared_ptr<>` instance.

Comment: Just tried your code on coliru, it works fine.?

Comment: @Mine I compile with with MSVC served with VS2015 RTM2

Comment: @SamVarshavchik.  Your point is a misleading opinion.  lock-free is required for high performance multi threaded code.  All of our implementations were developed with no massive amounts of time spent on shaky convoluted code.  Our $ cost savings in hardware were 100 times the cost of development.  10,000 times if you count customer retention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the race condition that can lead to every node in the queue waiting to be freed all at once - which is recursive and blows your stack.

If you change your test to use only one thread but don't pop, you get the same stack overflow error every time.

```
for (auto i = 1; i < 100000; i++) {
  queue.push(i);
  //int y;
  //queue.tryPop(y);
}
```

You need to unrecursive-ize deleting the chain of nodes:

```
__forceinline ~ConcurrentQueueNode() {
    if (!m_Next || m_Next.use_count() > 1)
        return;
    KillChainOfDeath();
}
void KillChainOfDeath() {
    auto pThis = this;
    std::shared_ptr<ConcurrentQueueNode> Next, Prev;
    while (1) {
        if (pThis->m_Next.use_count() > 1)
          break;
        Next.swap(pThis->m_Next); // unwire node
        Prev = NULL; // free previous node that we unwired in previous loop
        if (!(pThis = Next.get())) // move to next node
            break;
        Prev.swap(Next); // else Next.swap will free before unwire.
    }
}
```

I have never used shared_ptr before, so I don't know if there is a faster way to do this.  Also, since I have never used shared_ptr before, i don't know if your algorithm will suffer from ABA issues.  Unless there is something special in the shared_ptr implementation to prevent ABA I worry that previously freed nodes could be reused, spoofing CAS.  I never seemed to have that problem though when I ran your code.

Comment: I just realized i didn't put my full test code in here.  Woops.